# How do I get user input to ONLY equal 1-8?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to create a loop where the user is given choices 1-8 and if they do not choose 1-8, it loops them back around re-enter number 1-8. I am attempting to use a while loop with two conditions. What am I missing?

```py
fm_select = int(input("Enter a number 1-8"))
while fm_select <= 8 and fm_select >= 1:
```

Comment: Which programming language is that? What does not work with the current code?

Comment: python but I am also inexperienced

Answer (score 3):

Your ranges are wrong. You want the `while` loop to **fail** when they are **correct**, since you're trying to break out of the loop. So, you want your loop to check against every number that **isn't** between one and eight. Instead, do

```py
fm_select = 0
while (fm_select < 1 or fm_select > 8):
    fm_select = int(input("Enter a number between one and eight: "))
```

*"As long as their input is less than one or higher than eight, keep asking"*

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work

```
while(True):
    fm_select = int(input("Enter a number 1-8"))
    if 0 < fm_select < 8:
        break
    print("try again")
 print("you have entered %d" %(fm_select) )
```

Comment: Thanks this makes sense.  According to what I originally posted, is the syntax